# How to get a result from Rserve back in a variable in Apache Camel

Tags: java, r, apache-camel

Since there is not much documentation available for `Rcode` component of `Apache Camel`, I am not sure how I can get an output from a simple `R` code snippet that I am running through `Rcode`.

In my `RouteBuilder`, I have the following code:

```
from("activiti:testCamelTask:sendMsgToCamel",  "direct://rcode_source")
  .setBody(simple(rSourceCode))
  .to("rcode://localhost:6311/parse_and_eval?bufferSize=4194304")
  .end();
```

Where `rSourceCode` contains my `R` Code, which is:

```
c <-4;
print(c);
```

The code is running correctly and I am able to see the output in `Rserve` console.

I want the the value of the variable `c` back to my java code in a variable. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried `return(c);`?

Comment: @RalfStubner, how do I get it in a variable in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it more normal to use Apache Camel to send the result to some other component, possibly within the same program. But you can also store the data, e.g. via a [Bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html):

```
public class RserveCamel {
    public static class StoringBean {
        private REXP payload;
        public REXP getPayload() {
            return payload;
        }
        public void setPayload(REXP payload) {
            this.payload = payload;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        StoringBean storingBean = new StoringBean();

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:rcode")
                    .to("rcode:localhost:6311/eval?bufferSize=4194304")
                    .to("log:test?showBody=true&showHeaders=false")
                    .bean(storingBean, "setPayload");
            }
        });
        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = context.createProducerTemplate();
        context.start();
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:rcode", "c <- 4; print(c);");
        context.stop();
        System.out.println(storingBean.getPayload().asString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Only the `storingBean` instance had to be declared `final`.